# Fedora 20, How to add MariaDB TokuDB engine

Tags: mariadb, fedora-20

I was able to install MariaDB using this command:

sudo yum install mariadb-server mariadb-client

And it is working fine, but i am unable to install TokuDB engine as plugin. 
I have tried this:

sudo yum install MariaDB-tokudb-engine
but i am getting this error:

No package MariaDB-tokudb-engine available.

I guess its only for Fedora versions < 19

Is there any way to install TokuDB engine without custom build and compile of MariaDB on Fedora 20 Heisenbug?

Comment: It's not included in the Fedora-built community package, which you installed. I suggest filing a bug against Fedora and requesting to have it added.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing clean install of TokuDB 7.1.5 Community Edition for MariaDB 5.5.36 downloaded from Tokutek site and installed as binary.

Now i have this in MySQL as version:
5.5.36-tokudb-7.1.5-MariaDB

and i have all needed engines incuding TokuDB and Aria.